# Error loading GeoJSON data - XMLHttpRequest cannot load file?

Tags: openlayers, geojson

When I try to load a geojson format vector data, I get the following error :

**XMLHttpRequest cannot load file. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.**

But when I start a simple python server using http.server, everything seem to work. What's the problem?

Comment: I assume that you want to pass a path to this file, instead of url. You need ex. `http://localhost:3000/files/layer.geojson` instead of `C://Users/Data/layer.geojson`.

Comment: You may want to put the GeoJSON file in the same folder as your HTML file so you use a relative path (just file name) instead of absolute path, as you post your site localhost may not work for your users.